# How to produce separate scatter plots for each data in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I have list of lists where each list represent as a feature vector :

```
Matrix=[[12,43,65,78,54,43,76,98],
[23,465,90,9,32,75,324,12],
[67,43,21,56,32,7,4,9],
[3,9,0,67,23,12,65,97]]
```

i also have another feature vector as fvector:

```
fvector=[54,76,12,55,88,75,32,3]
```

I want to plot a scatter plot for each list of a matrix with fvector separately but when i tried plotting by iterating over each list then it plots on the same graph:

I tried this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for i in Matrix:
    plt.scatter(i,fvector)
```

**Output that i got is :**

[image: Output that i got is:]

but i want each matrix plot separately ,and is it possible to plot small separate graphs ?
Any reference or resource will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Just call `plt.figure()` before `plt.scatter()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the subplots to create multiple plots on the same figure.

```
for i, item in enumerate(Matrix,1):
    plt.subplot(2, 2, i)
    plt.scatter(item, fvector)
plt.show()
```

If we have more than four lists in the Matrix then we can divide them into groups of four and generate separate figures for each set of 4 lists. Please check below:

```
for j in range(0, len(Matrix), 4):  
    for i, item in enumerate(Matrix[j:j+4],1):
        plt.subplot(2, 2, i)
        plt.scatter(item, fvector)
    plt.show()
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks ,but what if i have 10 lists in Matrix.Its giving ValueError: num must be 1 <= num <= 4, not 5......how can i plot 2 or 3 graphs in each row .?

Comment: Then you just need to change plt.subpot(2,2,i) to plt.subplot(5,2,i) or plt.subplt(2,5,i). In other words you would need to find two values n and m such that n*m is equal to the length of Matrix list.

Comment: but it also reduce the size

Comment: I see. I guess then you should divide the Matrix into groups of 4 lists and keep generating the Plots.

Comment: like how can we do that ?will you please help me out

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in Matrix:
    plt.scatter(i,fvector)
    plt.show()
```

Should do it

Answer (score 0):

You need to use multiple axes using subplots

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2)
```

And the plot will look something like:

```
axs[0].plot(x1, y)
axs[1].plot(x2, y)
```